# Pick specific contours for ListContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I have 4D data that I would like to visualize specific 3D contours for. I have found that using this command

`ListContourPlot3D[data, Contours -> 5, Mesh -> None,  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

gives me a decent graph and indicates the contours on the side.
[image]

However, I don't want these contours to be picked automatically I would like to pick the values on my own. I've been through the documentation and it seems like there's an easy way to do this for the 2D contour case but I can't seem to figure out how it would work here for the 3D case. My data is of the form {x,y,z,value}. Please let me know if any data is needed here. I felt this was a more general question so I left it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. For anyone else who needs this

```
ListContourPlot3D[data, Contours -> {val1,val2}, Mesh -> None,  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

does the trick